# ¿Cómo resolver este problema de la biblioteca jspdf ... entradas permanecen en la misma línea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

He creado un formulario, pero todos los valores están en la misma línea. No sé cómo hacer el salto de línea o dejar cada valor separado en una línea. ¿Usted puede ayudarme?

**No quiero que ocurra eso**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Descripción**: Los valores están juntos y este es el problema o los valores no se mostrar.

Source-code

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <form id="nota" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="six columns">
               <label>Nombre</label>
               <input class="nombre u-full-width" id="nombre" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <label>Direccion</label>
               <input class="direccion u-full-width" id="direccion" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <label>Nombre del Madre</label>
               <input class="nombredelamadre u-full-width" id="nombredelamadre" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <label>Nombre del Padre</label>
               <input class="nombredelpadre u-full-width" id="nombredelpadre" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <button class="button-primary">PDF</button>  
             </div>
            </form> 
            </div>
        </body>
   <script>

      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      let button = document.querySelector(".button-primary");

      let nombre = document.querySelector("nombre");
      let direccion = document.querySelector("direccion");
      let nombredelpadre = document.querySelector("nombredelpadre");
      let nombredelamadre = document.querySelector("nombredelamadre");

      button.addEventListener('click', printPDF)
      function printPDF() {

         var name = `Nombre ${nombre.value}`; 
         var endereco = `Direccion ${direccion.value}`;
         var email = `Nombre de la Madre ${nombredelamadre.value}`; 
         var celular = `Nombre del Padre ${nombredelpadre.value}`; 

         pdf.text(10, 10, nombre + '\n');
         pdf.text(10, 10, direccion + '\n');
         pdf.text(10, 10, nombredelpadre + '\n');
         pdf.text(10, 10, nombredelamadre + '\n');

         pdf.save();
      }
   </script>
  </html>
```

**Quiero que esto suceda**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Descripción**: Los valores están separados y eso que quería hacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas mal en tu código:

1.- Por un lado lo que te indica @gaston-graciani de los `querySelectors`

2.- Por otro, estás asignando en las variables `name`, `endereco`, `email` y `celular` un `string` con los `values` de tus `inputs` pero luego estás usando el `input` en sí a la hora de escribir en el `pdf` (fíjate que estás haciendo `pdf.text(10, 10, nombre + '\n');` en vez de `pdf.text(10, 10, name);`)

3.- Por último, el método `pdf.text` acepta los valores x,y,texto como parámetros. Estás indicando 10 para las x y 10 también para las y por lo que está siempre escribiendo en la posición 10,10 de tu `pdf` (y de ahí que esté sobrescribiendo un texto encima del otro).

```js
const pdf = new jsPDF();
      let button = document.querySelector(".button-primary");

      let nombre = document.querySelector(".nombre");
      let direccion = document.querySelector(".direccion");
      let nombredelpadre = document.querySelector(".nombredelpadre");
      let nombredelamadre = document.querySelector(".nombredelamadre");

      button.addEventListener('click', printPDF)
      function printPDF() {
console.log(nombre.value);
         var name = `Nombre ${nombre.value}`; 
         var endereco = `Direccion ${direccion.value}`;
         var email = `Nombre de la Madre ${nombredelamadre.value}`; 
         var celular = `Nombre del Padre ${nombredelpadre.value}`; 

         pdf.text(10, 10, name);
         pdf.text(10, 20, endereco);
         pdf.text(10, 30, email);
         pdf.text(10, 40, celular);

         pdf.save();
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <form id="nota" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="six columns">
               <label>Nombre</label>
               <input class="nombre u-full-width" id="nombre" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <label>Direccion</label>
               <input class="direccion u-full-width" id="direccion" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <label>Nombre del Madre</label>
               <input class="nombredelamadre u-full-width" id="nombredelamadre" type="text" autocomplete="off">
               <label>Nombre del Padre</label>
               <input class="nombredelpadre u-full-width" id="nombredelpadre" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<button class="button-primary">PDF</button>  
             </div>
            </form> 
            </div>
        </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias y voy a añadir su nombre en la colaboración de este proyecto. ¿Puedo a añadir su nombre en la colaboración de este proyecto ?

Comment: Ahora entiendo que me equivoco al hacer el 'script.js' y gracias a la ayuda de ustedes. Voy a mejorar siempre.

Comment: No creo que sea necesario añadir ningún nombre como colaborador por esta simple duda.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estas declarando las variables que contienen el selector del evento q queres manipular, te estas olvidando q tipo de elemento estas seleccionando (Si es una clase, un id o en un elemento)

```
  let nombre = document.querySelector("nombre");
  let direccion = document.querySelector("direccion");
  let nombredelpadre = document.querySelector("nombredelpadre");
  let nombredelamadre = document.querySelector("nombredelamadre");
```

Parece que lo que queres hacer es llamar a los elementos cuya clase contienen nombre, direccion, nombredelpadre, nombredelamadre pero no estas aclarando que esta misma es una clase o un id, por lo tanto, al interpretar, el navegador busca un elemento inexistente.

```
  let nombre = document.querySelector(".nombre");
  let direccion = document.querySelector(".direccion");
  let nombredelpadre = document.querySelector(".nombredelpadre");
  let nombredelamadre = document.querySelector(".nombredelamadre");
```